# Issue moving project to Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, directx, linker-errors, visual-studio-2012

I've just moved over to Visual Studio 2012 RC to give it a test run. But I'm having problems with getting my DirectX 11 game project to work with it. When I build I get 1152 warnings that all look like this:

```
1>e:\program files (x86)\microsoft directx sdk (june 2010)\include\dwrite.h(4972): warning C4005: 'DWRITE_E_NOFONT' : macro redefinition
1>          c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\winerror.h(50217) : see previous definition of 'DWRITE_E_NOFONT'
```

They come from all the DirectX headers and each one is for a different macro. I also get some unresolved external symbols I didn't get before:

```
1>base.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl operator delete(void *,int,char const *,int)" (??3@YAXPAXHPBDH@Z) referenced in function __unwindfunclet$??__EgGame@@YAXXZ$0
1>game.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl operator delete(void *,int,char const *,int)" (??3@YAXPAXHPBDH@Z)
1>world.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl operator delete(void *,int,char const *,int)" (??3@YAXPAXHPBDH@Z)
```

The only place I would think `delete` would be overloaded is in `#include <crtdbg.h>`, which I am using in my project. But the thing is, all this working in Visual Studio 2010.

Not to sure what the problem is. Am I missing any steps when converting the projects?

I should also mention that my computer previously crashed (I only lost Windows, and the registry) so I've had to reinstall most of my programs. I don't know if this will come into play, but I haven't compiled the project on VS2010 since the crash.

Comment: Looks like it is a problem with the new C Run-Time lib included with the VS2012. A lot of similar problems here and there for the projects compiled with different older libraries.

Comment: @SergeyK. No, should I try that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to recompile all your libraries with VS2012 in order to fix this issue. It is a problem with the new C run-time library included with the VS2012.

Comment: Do I need the Windows 8 DirectX SDK? Because I don't want to use that. If I can't use the June 2012 SDK, I'll just stick with VS2010 for DirectX...

Comment: It certainly appears so. The VS2012 is a Release Candidate, so it is quite risky to use it for production.

Comment: Well that's a disappointment. I guess I'll just have to stick with VS2010 for my game development.